# how to handle white space in filename when using subprocess in python

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm using subprocess to remove files in python, some of the file name has white space in it. How could I handle this?
For example, I have a file named '040513 data.txt'

```
subprocess.call(['rm', '040513 data.txt'], shell=True)
```

But I got error like IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
How could I fix this?

Comment: Why are you using `subprocess` for this? You should be using [os.remove()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.remove).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can escape the whitespace, something like:

```
cmd = "rm 040513\ data.txt"
subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
```

Comment: You really want to avoid the `shell=True` instead; then you don't have to. See also [Actual meaning of `shell=True`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess)

Answer (score 1):

You can also pass a list of args to `call`. This takes cares of parameters and also you avoid the `shell=True` security issue:

```
subprocess.call(['rm', '040513 data.txt'])
```

If for any reason you wanted to use `shell=True` then you could also use quotes to *escape* blanks as you would do in a shell:

```
subprocess.call('rm "040513 data.txt"', shell=True)
```